# Can't get into my phone after erasing it through iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

I forgot my restrictions passcode so I looked at some websites and forums who told me to erase my iPhone from iCloud and to backup my iPhone.

I did this but unfortunately, now my iPhone is in lost mode and has been erased from iCloud and I can't get into my phone. How can I get back into my phone or reset it?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Lost Mode on your device by going to [icloud.com/#find](http://www.icloud.com/#find), selecting the device and clicking **Stop Lost Mode**.

Comment: Yes but how? It just says that the phone has been lost and I should call a certain number

Comment: I also deleted my device from my iCloud account thinking it would change something

Comment: @DrunkinLama Ah, you can always restore your device using iTunes. Turn your device off, then connect it to iTunes over USB whilst holding down the home button.

Comment: Where is édit? Is it in iCloud? If so where?

Comment: I did that but itunes says it needs my to unlock my pin which i can't reach since i'm locked out my phone i also tried taking my pin in and out of my iPhone but it still didm't work

Comment: I tried restoring my iphone again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You will have to restore your phone. It will ask for your apple id and password at some point in the restoration process (activation lock). Once you enter that, it will finish restoring, then you can restore your apps and data from an iTunes or iCloud backup.

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide to restore your iPhone and then make sure you know your Apple ID email and password.

https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201252

If you dont know your apple id email or password visit www.appleid.apple.com or www.appleid.com